# the operation couldn’t be completed. The parameter is incorrect when press F5

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

When I am trying to build a solution and press F5 it gives error

```
"The operation couldn’t be completed. The parameter is incorrect"
```

I have checked all the references the website is referring to. Deleted the same and re-added all the references. Still no use.

Any suggesstions.

Comment: In my case, it resolved by simply re-opening the solution

Comment: Yeah, I did the same. I copied the solution from the backup folder and replace the same and it worked.